# Windows function ReadFile keeps returning FALSE and don't know why

Tags: c, windows

It's quite a simple C code to read a file text, I've done this other times but don't know why now the ReadFile function keeps returning FALSE meaning it fails.

Obviously the text file input.txt exists and the CreateFile function succeeds (or at least doen't return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char ReadBuffer[256] = {0};
    HANDLE hFile1;
    int n = 0;
    DWORD bytesread = 5;

    printf("Press enter to read the file 'input.txt' ... ");
    getch();

    if ( (hFile1 = CreateFile(TEXT("input.txt"), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE))
    {
        printf("INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE");
        return -1;
    }

    if ( ReadFile(hFile1, ReadBuffer, bytesread, &bytesread, NULL) == FALSE )
    {
        printf("ReadFile ERROR");
        CloseHandle(hFile1);
        return -2;
    }

    printf("\n\nRead bytes: %d \n\n", bytesread);


    CloseHandle(hFile1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should use [GetLastError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679360%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to see why it is failing

Comment: Thnx, GetLastError gives me code 6, that states that the HANDLE is invalid; but when I compare the hFile1 with INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE I have no problem.

Comment: if (hFile1 = CreateFile(...) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)) Do you really think that this performs better than two lines: hFile1 = CreateFile(); if ( hFile1 == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)? I have no idea how this long line is executed, but this style can be the reason of some surprising errors.

Comment: Ok Alex, that was it. I guessed that with the bracket work it would be enough (although I supposed it would be bad styling) but looks like I was wrong. Thnx a lot, I'd try to avoid that bad practicing in the future.

Comment: Peter, the form you used may have been bad style, but the actual error was just the misplacement of your closing parenthesis `)`. It should have been to the left of the `==`.

Answer (score 4):

The error is a simple misplacement of a parenthesis.

```
if ( (hFile1 = CreateFile(TEXT("input.txt"), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
```

Comment: Hehe, nice demonstration of how the coding style is a bottomless source of bugs.